# Read structured data with start/end tags

Tags: python, numpy, io, genfromtxt

I have a data file portions of which look like

```
START
vertex 266.36 234.594 14.6145
vertex 268.582 234.968 15.6956
vertex 267.689 232.646 15.7283
END
START
vertex 166.36 23.594 4.6145
vertex 8.582 23.968 5.6956
vertex 67.689 32.646 1.7283
END
# [...]
```

i.e., blocks of three "vertices". I would now like to read the data as quickly as possible. So far, I'm going through the lines one by one,

```
data = numpy.empty((n, 3))

flt = numpy.vectorize(float)
for k in range(n):
    parts = f.readline().decode('utf-8').split()
    assert len(parts) == 4
    assert parts[0] == 'vertex'
    data[k] = flt(parts[1:])
```

but that is pretty slow.

Any hints?

Comment: `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) reads the file, line by line, and collects the split strings in a list of lists.  The arrays constructed once at the end.

Comment: With `data` initialized as dtype float, `data[k] = parts[1:]` should work.  `numpy` will convert the strings to floats during the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have just consumed the `START` line you could try something like

```
>>> i = iter(file.__next__, 'END\n')
>>> np.loadtxt(i, usecols=(1,2,3))
array([[266.36  , 234.594 ,  14.6145],
       [268.582 , 234.968 ,  15.6956],
       [267.689 , 232.646 ,  15.7283]])
```

I'm assuming that `loadtxt` is reasonably fast, but I don't know what the overhead of `iter` is.

Comment: I guess one could also use the `comments` argument to exclude START and END tags.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Good idea, provided you know how to get rid of the "some other data"

Comment: Yeah I can handle that separately. Removed from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why the need to decode from utf-8? The data you show implies that might not be needed.

The second thought that comes to mind is the array slicing on the last line. Since you have already checked that there are exactly 4 items, of which you plan to skip the first, depending on how numpy works, might it be an option to say:

```
data[k] = (float(parts[1]), float(parts[2]), float(parts[3]))
```

Comment: Is this faster than `flt(parts[1:])`? I guess not.

Comment: The conversion might be since it is trading the generality for a specific size, which ought in principle allow optimization. But I expect a bigger win from ditching the utf8 stuff.